# Ion shell pass args to alias

Tags: shell, redox-os

In `bash` shell, I can pass arguments to an alias like this:

```sh
alias vim="nvim -O $@"
```

Does `ion` shell have an equivalent? `alias vim="nvim -O @args"` is close, but it looks like it passes an extra argument at the beginning.

Something that slices the args array would work, but looks like `alias vim="nvim -O @args[1..]"` is not valid syntax.

Comment: Looked for a tag for an ion shell specific tag, but there doesn't seem to be one.

Comment: What's the point of having `$@`/`$args` there, why do you need positional parameters? Doesn't `alias vim = "nvim -O"` work fine?

Comment: What is the obsession with `alias` (everywhere, not just you ;-) )? . ... If your code really works, it is a major departure for how `alias` is supposed to work in every other shell (don't know about `ion` either). Passing and processing arguments in a block of user-defined code is the for `functions`. You can probably get the feature you want if you convert this to a function, i.e. `$[ARGS[1..]}`. Good luck.